# Registering multiple DbContext using Simple Injector

Tags: c#, entity-framework, simple-injector

I have two derived `DbContext` types in my application:

- `MyDbContext` which maps to a database that I can control
- `ExternalDbContext` which maps to database that I cannot control (this one's new and needs to be added)

In the application I'm also using the [Decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) where I have a `SaveChangesDecorator` class that wraps Business Logic. This decorator is injected a `DbContext` type and calls the `.SaveChanges()` method on it.

```
public class SaveChangesDecorator : IWhatever
{
    private readonly DbContext dbContext;
    private readonly IWhatever decoratee;

    public SaveChangesDecorator(DbContext dbContext, ...)
    {
         this.dbContext = dbContext;
         ...
    }

    public void Whatever()
    {
         this.decoratee.Whatever()
         this.dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Now it depends on the use case which (or both) derived DbContext gets injected in the Business Logic. I had the following registration:

```
var databaseContextRegistration = scopedLifestyle.CreateRegistration(
    () => new MyDbContext(connectionString), container);

container.AddRegistration(typeof(MyDbContext), databaseContextRegistration);
container.AddRegistration(typeof(DbContext), databaseContextRegistration);
```

Now I can't add `ExternalDbContext` to the registration, because that would be ambiguous. Would the best option be to register `DbContext` as a collection for this scenario?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Now I can't add `ExternalDbContext` to the registration, because that would be ambiguous.

Registering `ExternalDbContext` as `DbContext` not only is ambiguous in your registration, it is ambiguous in your application, because depending on `DbContext` is a [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) violation, assuming that `ExternalDbContext` has a different schema.

If it has a different schema, classes that use `DbContext` and expect your 'normal' database would break if you supply them with the `ExternalDbContext`.

This typically means that you give each context its own 'interface', which is what you are already doing. My advice therefore is to lose the `DbContext` registration and just register `ExternalDbContext` and `MyDbContext` and inside your decorator inject both instances.

Comment: Such a straightforward advice.